# Compilation error with React Redux based on a union type with undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, reducers

I'm currently doing a tutorial on using Redux with React and decided to do it with Typescript. I'm getting a compilation error where my store's state is of the type {posts: PostType[]}. However I get an error saying that

```
Type '{ posts: PostType[]; } | undefined' is not assignable to type '{ posts: PostType[]; }'
```

I'm not sure what to do because in my own code I don't explicitly suggest that posts may be undefined. Below are relevant points in the code.

```
// The component using redux
handleClick = () => {
        const post = this.props.post! as PostType
        this.props.deletePost(post.id)
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: {posts: PostType[]}, ownProps: Props) => {
    return {
        post: state.posts.find(post => {
            return post.id === parseInt(ownProps.match.params.post_id);
        })
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => {
    return {
        deletePost: (id: number) => {dispatch({type: 'DELETE_POST', id: id})}
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Post);
```

```
// The reducer
import { PostType } from "../components/Home";

const initState = {
    posts: [{id: 1, title: 'Doctors hate him', body: 'Discover the new trick to stay young', userId: 3}, 
            {id: 2, title: 'Fresh donuts', body: 'Hand-glazed', userId: 4}, 
            {id: 3, title: 'Duque dimite', body: 'El presidente colobiano dio su renuncia', userId: 5}]
}

const rootReducer = (state: {posts: PostType[]}  = initState, action: {type: string, id: number}) => { 
    if (action.type === 'DELETE_POST') {
        return {
            ...state,
            posts: state.posts.filter(post => post.id !== action.id)
        }
    }
}   


export default rootReducer;
```

Something weird that I noticed is that if I remove the if statement from the rootReducer function my code transpiles fine. I'm really stumped. I did try to research this question I found something that suggests that it might have to do with --strictNullChecks flag incompatibility with redux but I'm not sure. Thanks for the help.

Edit: Stack trace + component below

```
Post.tsx:48 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'posts' of undefined
    at Function.mapStateToProps [as mapToProps] (Post.tsx:48)
```

refers to this

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: {posts: PostType[]} , ownProps: Props) => {
    return {
        post: state.posts.find(post => {  // this line causes the error
            return post.id === parseInt(ownProps.match.params.post_id);
        })
    }
}
```

And I'll leave the component code below though I think that the code above is more relevant.

```
interface PostProps {
    post_id: string
}

interface Props extends RouteComponentProps<PostProps> {
    post?: PostType
    deletePost: (id: number) => void
}

class Post extends Component<Props, {}> {

    handleClick = () => {
        const post = this.props.post! as PostType
        this.props.deletePost(post.id)
    }

    render() {
        let post;
        if (this.props.post !== undefined) {
            const postData = this.props.post! as PostType
            post = 
            <div className="post">
                <h4 className="center">{postData.title}</h4>
                <p>{postData.body}</p>
                <div className="center">
                    <button className="btn grey" onClick={this.handleClick}>Delete Post</button>
                </div>
            </div>;
        } else {
            post = <h4>Loading post...</h4>;
        }
        return (
            <div className="container">
                {post}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar enogh with typescript but based on the ts error, it seems you should add `| undefined` also to state type:
`const mapStateToProps = (state: {posts: PostType[] } | undefined , ownProps: Props) => {`

Comment: Good idea but I had already tried this, I get the same error unchanged even if I do that

Comment: Can you also share the stack trace + component implementation too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this was an error with my reducer. I previously checked the action.type of the argument and then returned a new state, but in the case that it wasn't of that type I returned void thinking it was fine because I hadn't passed it actions of any other type in my code. Well actually, the reducer is called in the background and thus it caused this bug because now state was undefined. So always return the existing state as a default in the reducer!

Only fix necessary below:

```
const rootReducer = (state: {posts: PostType[]}  = initState, action: {type: string, id: number}) => { 
    if (action.type === 'DELETE_POST') {
        return {
            ...state,
            posts: state.posts.filter(post => post.id !== action.id)
        }
    }
    return {
        ...state      // We do this because the reducer is called by something that was not our dispatch
    }
}
```